# Reflux stores not listening to actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, refluxjs

**Edit:**

I feel silly now. **The problem was I wasn't requiring my store anywhere in my code, so it was never actually being created.**

My refluxjs store is not calling its callback when I call the action it's listening to. Here is the relevant code:

**Actions:**

```
module.exports = require("reflux").createActions([
    "createUser"
]);
```

**Store:**

```
var userActions = require("../actions/user-actions");

module.exports = require("reflux").createStore({
    listenables: userActions,

    onCreateUser: function() {
        console.log("onCreateUser called", arguments);
    }
});
```

**Component that fires the action:**

```
var React = require("react"),
    userActions = require("../../actions/user-actions");

var Login = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            name: ""
        };
    },

    updateName: function(event) {
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value
        });
    },

    // Action gets called here
    submit: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Creating user", this.state.name);
        userActions.createUser(this.state.name);
    },

    render: function() {
        var name = this.state.name;

        return (
            <div className='login'>
                <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
                    <input value={name} onChange={this.updateName} />
                    <button>Create</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

When I submit the form in the `Login` component, the `submit` method is called without throwing any errors, but the `onCreateUser` method of my store is never called.

The examples on the reflux github page seem fairly straightforward and this is almost exactly the same as the example for using the `listenables` property on a store.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edit … can you maybe make that bold or something? I feel as silly as you, but would have found the problem earlier, had I read the edit-part as a solution. :)

Comment: @mknecht I've bolded the edit and moved it to the top

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since stores usually are hooked up to a component, and be required in that way, you could create a test component that just logs out to the console:

```
var store = require('path/to/your/store'),
    React = require('react'),
    Reflux = require('reflux');

var ConsoleLogComponent = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ 
        Reflux.listenTo(store, "log")
        // you may add more stores here that calls the log method
    ],
    log: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div />
    }
});
```

You can then put this console component where ever and just have a sanity check that the store works.